# Can I lock an account to a specific smart contract?

Tags: blockchain, smart-contract-wallets

I want to lock an account to a specific Smart contract. So that the account will allow only the transactions from this specific smart contract. If some other smart contract tries to interact with this account, it will not be able to. How can I do this?

[image]

I got this doubt based on the Zether paper (screenshots attached) in which it is given that we can lock an account to a contract.

Comment: Transactions don't come from smart contracts. They only come from "users" (EOAs)

Comment: Also, when I send you some tokens or NFTs, I am not interacting with your account. At all.

Comment: Why don't you just inverse, and only allow an account to interact with a contract?

Comment: If you really want this functionality use an onchain wallet solution like gnosis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't directly "lock" an **EOA (External Owned Account)** to only interact with a specific smart contract, as it's not a built-in feature of EVM.

However, you can design a **proxy** contract that will interact only with a specific address or contract. But still you can't prevent someone to interact with you (e.g, sending ERC20 tokens, NFTs, etc.)

Comment: Okay, I got this. But, I have edited my question - with reference to a paper from where i got this doubt.

Comment: May I please know the answer for my updated (modified) question?

Comment: You can't stop others from sending tokens to your account or adding your address to their smart contracts. Similarly, I can't prevent anyone from using my name in their app, Excel sheet, or any doc.

Zether doesn't change this because it focuses on confidentiality and doesn't modify the core smart contract functionality. For example, if you use Zether for confidential transactions, your account balances and transfers will be encrypted, but the account locking mechanism remains the same, using a proxy contract to control access.

Comment: @GPavithra Zether will just make sure that your contract is allowed to interact with specific contracts and EOA, but it can't prevent contracts to interact with you. To simplify you can prevent with whom your interacting but not who's interacting with you

Comment: Okay, is it like this?

Comment: it is like what?  @GPavithra

Comment: Okay, is it like this? In the Zether paper, they have given we can lock our accounts to a smart contract. This means that the smart contract can be made to interact with specific eoas and contracts. (not the other way round, i.e., we (eoa account) can interact with only specific contracts, cannot send/receive funds to/from others except this contract ??

Comment: @GPavithra I didn’t read the whole whitepaper, but again you can control who your smart contract is interacting with, but not the opposite! We’re far from the original question if you want to ask anything specific regarding Zether I suggest you to open a new question.

Comment: Okay thank you got it